# Best practice style -- method names with delegates and ownership

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

Is it a good practice or a bad practice to have same-named methods across classes, particularly where inheritance and/or protocols are involved?

For example, I have a protocol of some kind:

```
@protocol DataReceiver <NSObject>

- (void)handleNewData:(id)data;

@end
```

And I have a controller class that owns some stuff, such as

```
@interface OwnerOfAllThings <DataReceiver>

//this child does NOT conform to DataReceiver
@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeOwnedModel myChild;

@end
```

But the child is opaque, so my implementation of `-handleNewData:` is basically just a pass-through and calls a method in the child that takes care of the actual handling. So my question is, although it's not functionally so different, is it a bad idea to put an identically named method in `SomeOwnedModel`, being that it might be confused with the declaration in the protocol? Or should it in fact be exactly the same, for consistency?

i.e., which is better (assuming that the `SomeOwnedModel.h` declares the appropriate method):

```
@implementation OwnerOfAllThings

- (void)handleNewData:(id)data {

    //Option 1:
    [self.myChild handleNewData:data]; //OR...

    //Option 2:
    [self.myChild ownerReceivedNewData:data]; //or whatever else

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `OwnerOfAllThings` is simply invoking the method in the child, I might be inclined to keep the same method names, possibly even have `SomeOwnedModel` conform to the same protocol. If you use the "use unique names" pattern, I can only imagine how unwieldy it would become if you had three or four levels of classes or if you had a ton of methods in your protocol, being forced to come up with arbitrarily unique names for each.

By way of example, I have `NSOperation` based framework for `NSURLSession`, with a session manager object (a wrapper for `NSURLSession`), and a bunch of individual `NSOperation` classes (one for download tasks, one for data tasks, etc.). In this case, while `NSURLSession` conforms to not only `NSURLSessionDelegate`, it also conforms to `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`, `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`, etc. (because that's how `NSURLSession` works). But when this session manager receives one of these task-related delegate calls, it simply routes the event to the appropriate operation object. So to make this clear, I made the various operation objects conform to the appropriate protocol (e.g. download operation conforms to `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`, data operation conforms to `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`, etc.). The end result is that despite a dizzying collection of classes and protocols, the intent is unambiguous.

So, bottom line, if the parent is simply routing the event to the appropriate child and offering no material contribution beyond that, I'd be inclined to use same methods (and possibly same protocol). But if the parent class is offering something substantively richer/different, functionally, over what the child is performing, then a unique name would probably be appropriate.

---

As an aside, when coming up with your method names, I might suggest a method name that distinguishes "I received a bit of data and more may be coming" (i.e. `didReceive...`) vs. "I received all of the data" (i.e. `didComplete...`). This is an informal convention Apple uses in `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLSession`, and following it might be helpful to make your intent clear.

Comment: Thanks for the note. All good points. I can't make `SomeOwnedModel` conform to the same protocol, because there are actually other methods in the protocol which wouldn't apply to it -- but what do you think of creating some kind of protocol-inheritance-tree to abstract away shared methods? i.e., `@protocol DataHandler <NSObject>` and then `@protocol DataReceiver <DataHandler>` and `@protocol DataResponder <DataHandler>` (or something less ambiguous but similarly implicative)

Comment: Sure. Or you can have one protocol for child events, one for parent-unique events, and then have the parent conform to both (like `NSURLSession` does), but the child only conforms to the child-specific protocol. Use whatever approach you think is least ambiguous for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to name a method is always to try to accurately describe (beware of excessive verbosity) what the method does. If both your methods do exactly the same it's probably a good idea to extract that functionality to a self-contained class.

Often the convention is followed in iOS to name delegate methods like the one you have shown in the following form:

```
-(void)dataSource:(DataSource*)dataSource didReceiveNewData:(id)data {
   //Call your "child" object here
   [self.myChild doAWithData:data];
}
```

Where `dataSource` is the object that calls the delegate method.

In my opinion you're running into this problem because you're not accurately describing what the method actually does by using "handle" data.

Perhaps a good source for standards is [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingFunctions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001283-BAJGGCAD).

Comment: Good point, precise descriptions are helpful. In this case, the implementation of handling varies between subclasses of `SomeOwnedModel`, so that direction has limited options, but it's good to keep in mind.